# Get first line by git log with a single command on windows

Tags: windows, git, git-log

Seems to be pretty simple question that drives me crazy already. Trying get the first line from the commit list that I've got by following command:

> E:\Repos\reports>git log --oneline --reverse
>   origin/master..feature/a123

Getting following output

```
d8c38ac Dummy change to invoke deploy
aaca9eb (HEAD -> feature/a123, origin/feature/a123) Add transation isolation
```

Then trying to do

> E:\Repos\reports>git log --oneline --reverse
>   origin/master..feature/a123 -n 1

and doesn't matter do I use `--reverse` or not, I'm always getting `aaca9eb` commit

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, that's frustrating because the limiting of commits by number (`-n`) happens *before* the `--reverse`.

Though you can pipe it to a tail :

```
git log --oneline --reverse origin/master..feature/a123 | tail -1
```

Comment: I'm on windows.

Comment: @DmitrijKultasev Yes, I didn't ask but it won't work in Windows cmd. However, you can do that in the git bash terminal of "Git for Windows".

Comment: @DmitrijKultasev Download the "tail" command line tool for windows. https://www.windows-commandline.com/tail-command-for-windows/

Comment: @Mr.Black Hey, that's very neat. Love it.

Comment: I'll do that in powershell. I just thought that there could be native git command for that.